# Writting value at the end of 2d array

Tags: c, arrays

I have an 2d array . The 1st dimension has fixed size and i dynamicly create the 2nd dimension. e.g

```
    int **arr;
    *arr=( int * ) malloc ( X * sizeof ( int )) // X is input from user
```

What i want to do is create 2nd dimension and write value at the end of it.

For example i create 2nd dimension for arr[0] using

```
arr[0]=( int * ) malloc ( 2 * sizeof ( int ))
```

and then i want to write value in this 2nd dimension but without knowing the index. A lot of programming languages has method `array.push` which push item at the end of the array without knowing index or length of the array. How can i achieve such result in C? Is it possible?

Comment: In other languages you *do* know the length of the array, and the index to set the value of.

Comment: There is no C function to do what you ask. Your C 2D array is just a data structure, it doesn't have any built-in methods to operate on it. If you want to have a "push/pop" type functionality you would need to write your own functions to accomplish this or find a library that does provide what you are looking for.

Comment: if so , how can find size of 2nd dimension? I can use sizeof ( arr ) to get size of 1st dimension but cant figure out how to do it with 2nd

Comment: You allocated space for the "columns" so you do know the size of that dimension. Keep track of the last empty index so you can write your "push" function. Each time you attempt to "push" check if that array has room and if so update that element and increment the last index... something like that..

Comment: @Abdir Actually, you *can't* use `sizeof(arr)` to get the size of the 1st dimension, if it's dynamically allocated. If it's not dynamically allocated, then note that *`sizeof` is just the compiler remembering the size for you* -- it doesn't let you do anything you couldn't do without it.

Comment: `int **` Is not a 2D array. It is not even a 1D array, but a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: NO. You need to know the last index of the memory allocated via a pointer. **There is no way** of knowing the memory allocated for a pointer, so **you need to know** the last index for each column. Applying `sizeof` on a pointer gives you the memory occupied by a pointer (most often 4 or 8 bytes), and **not the memory allocated by the pointer**. This is a fundamental difference between pointers and arrays. They are not the same, although arrays decay to pointers when passed as arguments to functions.

Assuming your  2D array has NROWS and NCOLS, what you need is:

```
arr = malloc(NROWS * sizeof(int*)); // allocate memory for first dim, i.e. for rows
```

then allocate memory for each row, e.g. for the 5-th row:

```
arr[5] = malloc(NCOLS * sizeof(int)); // allocate NCOLS for the 5-th row
```

In general you allocate memory for the second dimension in a loop:

```
for(size_t i = 0 ; i < NCOLS; ++i)
    free(arr[i]);
```

Then don't forget to release the memory at the end, in reverse order:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < NCOLS; ++i)
    free(arr[i]); // release memory for cols
free(arr); // release memory for rows
```

However, I recommend you use a 1D array instead (in case the dimension is the same for each column), and map from 1D to 2D and viceversa. It's better this way since the data is stored contiguously (better data locality) and there are no cache misses.

If you switch to C++, then you can use the standard container [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), which "knows" its indexes, and you can add at the end via [`std::vector::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) or [`std::vector::emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) member functions.